# How to data-bind an iframe src attribute?

Tags: data-binding, iframe, knockout.js

Is there a way to data bind the `src` attribute of an `iframe` with knockout to an item in my modelView? This...

```html
<iframe data-bind="src: BioLink" width="100%" height="300">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

...didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [`attr` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html), like this:

```html
<iframe data-bind="attr: {src: BioLink}" width="100%" height="300">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```